# Why is my mesh transparent in viewport shading?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

So i'm a newbie, just started watching Blender Guru's "donut tutorial"
and i'm on part 6 level 1, when you try to render the thing that you've made.
i made a donut, and when i pressed "Viewport Shading"
my donut is gone..

This is the mesh i've made
[image]

And this is the mesh when i clicked "Viewport Shading
[image: "]

i can't find anything on the internet, or i just couldn't understand...

Comment: maybe you have an AMD graphic card, switch to previous driver, or in the Properties panel > Render > Performance, enable High Quality Normals

Comment: @moonboots ah yeah i have AMD graphic card.. Okay i'll try it out and came back if it fix the issue or not.. thanks!..

Comment: @moonboots okay the Render Properties > Performance > Check High Quality Normals is Working, thanks!